# Deep animator won't install

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to install deep animator and I'm having this error :

```
Collecting scikit-image==0.14.0
  Using cached scikit-image-0.14.0.tar.gz (27.0 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     
    Complete output (46 lines):
    Partial import of skimage during the build process.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\mati_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-26r7l_5j\scikit-image\setup.py", line 111, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\mati_\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\mati_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-26r7l_5j\scikit-image\setup.py", line 70, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('skimage')
      File "c:\users\mati_\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1018, in add_subpackage
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "c:\users\mati_\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 984, in get_subpackage
        config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
      File "c:\users\mati_\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 926, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "skimage\setup.py", line 14, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('feature')
      File "c:\users\mati_\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1018, in add_subpackage
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "c:\users\mati_\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 984, in get_subpackage
        config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
      File "c:\users\mati_\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 926, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "skimage\feature\setup.py", line 22, in configuration
        cython(['_haar.pyx'], working_path=base_path)
      File "C:\Users\mati_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-26r7l_5j\scikit-image\skimage\_build.py", line 41, in cython
        raise RuntimeError('Cython >= %s is required to build scikit-image from git checkout' \
    RuntimeError: Cython >= 0.23 is required to build scikit-image from git checkout
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built geometry.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built transform.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built interpolation.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built _draw.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built corner_cy.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built censure_cy.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built orb_cy.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built brief_cy.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built _texture.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built _hessian_det_appx.c
    Cython >= 0.23 not found; falling back to pre-built _hoghistogram.c
    ----------------------------------------
```

I have installed the lastest version of sci-kit image but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What Python environment do you have installed (stock, Anaconda, etc.) What command(s) did you use to try and install this package? Do you have Cython installed? This type of information is important to have in your initial post.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

Answer (score 0):

Please install cython first by below command in anaconda prompt.

```
conda install -c anaconda cython
```

once it's done, try to install  sci-kit image then it will work.